# How to cause ElasticSearch to reject child index attempts for non-existent parents?

Tags: elasticsearch

The default behavior of ElasticSearch when indexing a child document underneath a parent ID, is to index the child document regardless of whether the parent document actually exists or not.

The child document will go into the index with the parent_id set to the parent specified, despite the fact that there is no parent document present in the index.

I have searched the ES documentation (and source code to some degree) but cannot seem to find an obvious way to change this behavior.

I would like to cause ES to reject a child index attempt if the parent ID does not exist.

I am trying to avoid hack solutions like clean up jobs, additional queries etc... These are a last resort if there is truly no proper way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with Elasticsearch for a while I've found that there are a number of default behaviors that I don't like and I've built up a framework to enforce the behaviors I'd rather have.  I understand your desire to be able to set a flag or option to prevent orphan child inserts, but I think you will have to to wrap your inserts with a query and test to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm just going to accept it because I came to the same conclusion myself after going through the source code because the documentation is full of holes.